# Magento 2 installation. Too many redirects

Tags: magento, magento2

I spent 2 days around the net and no solution works
I just followed this tutorial

https://www.snel.com/support/how-to-install-magento-2-on-centos-7/

Everything goes fine with installation. When I call my URL to do the online installation it's gives mee the redirect error, and the address bar go to **mydomain.com/pub/setup**

I tried this solution https://www.codealist.com/magento-2-install-redirect-loop/ and this https://www.evermoretechnologies.com/blog/2018/07/redirect-loop-on-magento-2-web-installer/ that more seems near to my case, but no luck.

Why it goes on that directory that also seems to not exist.

Hope you can help me (please)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and found a **temporary solution**:

- disabled http to https forwarding at my hosting provider
- cleared cache and cookies
- finally got access to the magento website with http://www

But:
If I visit https:// I got the redirect loop again ...

At least you can access your website ... I dont know how it works with https.

**EDIT: Full Solution**

As mentioned above:

- disable http to https forwarding at your hosting provider
- clear cache and cookies
- access your magento website, go to your admin panel
- go to Stores > Configuration > General > Web
- change all your url´s to https urls (base, unsecure and secure)
- say "yes" to using of secure urls
- enable http to https forwarding at your hosting provider

Otherwise you will get "Too many redirects". Your hosting provider will forward you to https, magento forward you by default to http, hosting provider to https and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue and i've resolved this issue by adding the below text in .htaccess on Magento 2.4.x webroot

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "https" HTTPS=on
```